# PHP download file from SFTP

Tags: php, linux, ssh, sftp

I'm trying to download files from another server using ssh2. I already can execute commands with ssh2, but i need to download a file located in /root/
I tried with:

```
header("Content-type: text/plain");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=backup.vps");
echo file_get_contents('ssh2.sftp://' . $row['login'] . ':' . $row['senha'] . 'pass@'. $row['ip'] . ':22/root/backup.vps');
```

But it send a blank file. What's the problem?

Comment: What does the  `file_get_contents()` return? Do you see warnings in the log? Does `file_get_contents()` support `sftp` protocol?

Comment: file_get_contents returns nothing, If i try to use It in a variable, it's null

Comment: Is it `null` or `false`?

Comment: What does `$row['senha'] . 'pass` mean?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolved it by changing from this:

```
header("Content-type: text/plain");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=backup.vps");
echo file_get_contents('ssh2.sftp://' . $row['login'] . ':' . $row['senha'] . 'pass@'. $row['ip'] . ':22/root/backup.vps');
```

To this:

```
$result = file_get_contents('ssh2.sftp://' . $row['login'] . ':' . $row['senha'] . 'pass@'. $row['ip'] . ':22/root/backup.vps');
header("Content-type: text/plain");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=backup.vps");
echo $result;
```